# Blender texture paint without perspective-paint

Tags: sculpting, texture-painting, sculpt-mode, texture-paint-mode

In texture painting, the way the object is viewed on is determining how the color is applied. In sculpting mode, this is not the case, as the blue circle around the cursor automatically adjusts it on the top of a face.

[image]

I wanted to know if it is possible to use this " on top of a face " way not in sculpting, but in texture painting.
When I normally paint something in texture paint from a certain perspective, it looks fine from that particular perspective:
[image]

When in reality, it looks like this:

[image]

I basically want to have a feature that makes it not important from what perspective I am painting the cube, so that it always gets applied in a non-stretched way. That the texture painting cursor / circle also automatically adjusts itself on the top of each face. Like seen in the first picture, like with sculpt mode.

Comment: I think this doesn't exist yet and it is a request

Comment: If you would like to suggest this as a feature you should suggest it on [Right-Click Select](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in texture painting mode, the brush strokes do not maintain the perspective of the surface when painting from different angles. However, in sculpting mode, the brush cursor adjusts to the surface of the model and considers the perspective, resulting in more intuitive sculpting interactions.

However, there is a way to achieve consistent and non-stretched texture painting on a cube. By utilizing UV mapping, you can unwrap the cube's faces and directly apply the brush strokes on the UV map.

[image]

By painting directly on the UV map, the textures will be accurately applied to the cube's faces without stretching or distortion. However, please note that this process may have its own minor flaws.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this is not the best way of handling this. Is the "projection paint technique" an official known technique to the 3D world not available in blender, or was it just a description of you?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the suggested approach is not the best way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: While the term 'projection paint technique' is known, I have no idea how popular it is in the 3D world, and it is not specifically available as a separate feature in Blender.

Comment: However, it's worth noting that the terms 'texture paint' and 'projection paint' are sometimes used interchangeably. Texture paint generally refers to the broader process of painting or applying textures directly onto a model's surface using brushes or other tools. On the other hand, projection paint is a specific technique within texture painting that involves projecting textures onto a model's surface based on its UV mapping.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion caused by using the term 'projection paint technique' in this context. It appears that what you're looking for is a tool or feature that adjusts the cursor to the surface of the model and takes into account the perspective while texture painting. Unfortunately, Blender's Texture Paint mode does not currently provide an automatic cursor adjustment feature based on the surface and perspective

Comment: It's okay, thank you for the deeper explanation.